# How to disable serial port using devcon

Tags: windows, cmd, device, device-manager, devcon

I am trying to disable usb-serial ch340 port using devcon as shown in picture[image]. I tried following commands `devcon disable usb*`, `devcon disable com*` as shown in picture but did not work.[image] How can I disable it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be much too late, but I just had and solved the same message.

The solution was to open cmd as an administrator and call

```
devcon disable usb*
```

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work, (PID_1016 this is just an example).

```
 devcon.exe disable *PID_1016
```